# Centos Supervisord Python 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'process_num'

Tags: python, centos, supervisord

Im doing the following in supervisord:

```
[program:inf_svr]
process_name=inf_svr%(process_num)s
directory=/opt/inf_api/
environment=USER=root,PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/
command=python /opt/inf_api/inf_server.py --port=%(process_num)s
startsecs=2
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
numprocs_start=8080
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log
```

This works just fine on Ubuntu but in Centos6.5 I get the following error being returned from the python process

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'process_num'

I can manually start the process passing --port=8080 and --port="8080" and the script functions just fine
why might it work in one and not the other?

Comment: Could it be that the `command` value doesn't support `%(process_num)s` style formatting? What happens if you just put in a plain number?

Comment: running with --port=-8080 or --port='8080' works fine, but Im wondering whyn it works on ubuntu but not on Centos  With numprocs=4 it spawns 4 tornado servers on ubuntu running on ports 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083.  Centos it throws the error

Comment: so it looks like something is going on with how centos and/or python are trying to process the process_num that I am trying to send to the command. Building a complete second setup - but after spending 2 days on this im tempted to handle this in the tornado app and just not have supervisord attempt to pass the port number